# MVVM - Make ObservableCollection filter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to create a list which I can filter.
Firstly in my xaml.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ExpectedGroup"                               
          Source="{Binding ExpectedListView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
          <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="InductedSites" />                           
          </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
           <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="InductedSites"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="PN_EmploymentType"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FullName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

and in my viewmodel

```
private ICollectionView _expectedListView;
    public ICollectionView ExpectedListView
    {
        get { return _expectedListView; }
        set { _expectedListView = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ExpectedListView"); }
    }

private ObservableCollection<BoonPerson> _expectedList;
    public ObservableCollection<BoonPerson> ExpectedList
    {
        get { return _expectedList; }
        set { _expectedList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ExpectedList"); }
    }
```

I am first populating my observablecollection and then moving the data into the ICollectionView

```
ExpectedList = await _clockInService.LoadExpectedList();
ExpectedListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ExpectedList);
```

**Edit
and the listbox

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="lbExpected" 
 DataContext="{StaticResource ExpectedGroup}"
 Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                Margin="0,2,0,0" FontSize="10.667">
```

But the list always remains empty.
I have proven the process works by making my listbox itemsource = ExpectedListView.
I have searched everywhere and cannot find what I am doing wrong.
Appreciate any pointers. Scott

Comment: I wrote [this](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Reactive/blob/master/Gu.Wpf.Reactive/FilteredView.cs#L23) for filtering. It is strongly typed so you get intellisense and testable.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But it doesn't help me with the immediate question, and what I am doing wrong. I will look at this further.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExpectedGroup}}" .../>
```

Not DataContext="{StaticResource ExpectedGroup}".

Comment: I'm afraid that still doesn;t work. I am currently going through every possible solution. Can't believe I'm having such problem.